# What does 'put some dust on your face' mean?

Tags: idiom, colloquial, lyrics

The Eisbrecher song Fanatica has the line "let me put some dust on your face". I assume this is a literal translation of a German expression, but I can't figure out what it means.

Comment: Das ist doch eine Frage nach einer englischen Formel? M.E. off topic.

Comment: It asks for the meaning of an non-understood English formular.

Comment: It's probably a drug-related phrase. Given the overall quality of the lyrics I wouldn't spend much time thinking about it.

Comment: @userunknown: Aber die Frage ist, welcher **deutsche** Satz hier eventuell schlecht übersetzt wurde, und hierfür ist primär Wissen über die deutsche Sprache erforderlich. Insofern ist die Frage schon on-topic (und vergleichbar mit einer Frage über die Bedeutung des Worts *Oldtimer).*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Danke shön! Das ist was ich genau gemeint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of a corresponding German expression, certainly not a common one.

Comment: I also don't know exactly what they mean by "feed my fire" and "heat my wire" ... well, that's lyrics for you.

Comment: Sieht für mich wie ein Kommentar, nicht wie eine Antwort aus.

Comment: It's got three upvotes, so who am I to argue?

Comment: I never hear english songs with nonsensical lyrics, so I assumed the same would be true with german - I guess eisbrecher are just weird?

Comment: You mean all the lyrics of all songs ever make sense to you? You either have a very eclectic taste in music, or "sense" just doesn't meant the same to both of us ...

Answer (score 1):

**First:**
The Song "Fanatica" (published 2003) is not from "Rammstein" but from "Eisbrecher" (Eisbrecher = ice breaker). (There are more NDH-bands than just Rammstein).
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWu2il7pckY

**Second:**
Lyrics doesn't always need to mean something.

Maybe you understand the mood that should be expressed by this song if you read the complete lyrics and its translation.

### Complete lyrics:

> Wir tanzen elektrisch
>   Ganz hektisch
>   Wir schwingen fantastisch
>   Elastisch
>   Wir drehn uns narkotisch
>   Hyperhypnotisch
>   Wir tanzen den Rhythmus
>   Wo ich mit muss
>
> Feed my fire
>   Let me put some dust on your face
>   Heat my wire
>   You make me feel ecstatic
>   Make me dance fanatic tonight
>
> Tanz - fanatica
>   Tanz - fanatica
>
> Wir tanzen elektrisch
>   Ganz hektisch
>   Wir schweben erotisch
>   Neoexotisch
>   Wir wiegen uns kryptisch
>   Apokalyptisch
>   Wir tanzen ekstatisch
>   Wir tanzen fanatisch
>
> Feed my fire ...
>
> (repeated refrain)

### Translation of the german parts:

> We dance electric
>   Totally hectic
>   We swing fantastic
>   Elastic
>   We turn narcotic
>   Hyperhypnotic
>   We dance the rhythm
>   that I must follow 1)
>
> Feed my fire ...
>
> dance - fanatica 2)
>
> We dance electric
>   Totally hectic
>   We levitate erotic
>   Neoexotic
>   We sway cryptic
>   Apocalyptic
>   We dance ecstatic
>   We dance fanatic
>
> Feed my fire ...

1) "Der Rhythmus wo ich (immer) mit muss" is phrase that is hard to translate. I lives from its rhyme.

2) "fanatica" is neither a german nor an english word. Maybe it should be an exotic version of "fanatic"

Comment: You're right about the band! I was listening to rammstein when I typed the question, and just put the wrong name in. Thanks for pointing it out - I've edited the question.

Answer (score -1):

Just imagine how you would put dust on someone's face. There are several options, of course, from using a glitter-stick or make-up powder to the more colorful hand-toss one would use in a motion reminiscient of sexual innuendo. The choice, I think, was left up to the listener to interpret for themselves. Also, one could arguably say that "dust" could allude to the somewhat obscure "stardust", which is a euphemism for a particular drug. And no, if you don't know, I won't tell you. Google it yourself, I'm sure you'll find out.
Anyways, those are my theories, feel free to have your own. =D